# samba logs be parsed to a user-friendly graph/report

Tags: ubuntu, logging, samba

can samba logs be parsed to a user-friendly graph/report.
Is there any way to get samba logs in a user friendly graph or report.

Regards,
Muralikrishna

Answer (score 1):

You can output the syslog messages to your server of choice (make sure that Samba was built with the configure --with-syslog option).  For searches and charting, check out [Logzilla](http://www.logzilla.pro).  They have a free version for small networks.

Comment: Looks useful. Let me verify it and get back to you.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to configure logzilla

Comment: What portion of it do you need help configuring?